# Como tener varias consultas de la misma tabla mostrando solo un registro de datos pero el total de suma PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tablas

Buen día.

Estoy intentando realizar múltiples consultas en la misma tabla. La tabla tiene varios registros repetidos los cuales identifico por un número de 'OP'.

Quisiera que en la tabla me muestre solamente una fila de datos de codigo, descripción pero que también sume todas las cantidades de esos registros y cuente cuantos son en total, ahora tengo esto..

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'password','BD')or die(mysqli_error($mysql));

    $consulta = "SELECT SUM(a9) AS 'suma' FROM suaje WHERE OP='30037-C'  ";
    $guardar = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_array($guardar);
    $suma = $datos['suma'];
    echo $suma;
?>
```

Esa consulta anterior me arroja al inicio de la pagina el "5600" que es la suma.

Y tengo la otra consulta que es de esta manera para mostrar los datos de esa OP..

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'password','BD')or die(mysqli_error($mysql));
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM suaje WHERE OP='30037-C'  ";
    $guardar = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
?>

<?php while($row = $guardar->fetch_assoc()){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['fecha']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['OP']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['codigo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['a9']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Esa última consulta me arroja todos los registros de ese OP.

Lo que quiero hacer es que solo me muestre una fila de datos pero con la suma de las cantidades de la primer consulta (solo un código y registro pero la suma de todos los 400)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Basicamente queres un group by... lee sobre eso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo este esquema:

```
CREATE TABLE suaje (
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
    OP VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    codigo VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    a9 INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

Y esta data de prueba:

```
INSERT INTO suaje
    (fecha, OP, codigo, descripcion, a9)
VALUES
    ('2023-02-17 06:51:50', '30037-C', 'PUR-CT-100221-9', 'UNIT CARTON', 400),
    ('2023-02-17 06:52:15', '30037-C', 'PUR-CT-100221-9', 'UNIT CARTON', 400),
    ('2023-02-17 06:52:52', '30037-C', 'PUR-CT-100221-9', 'UNIT CARTON', 400),
    ('2023-02-17 06:53:27', '30037-C', 'PUR-CT-100221-9', 'UNIT CARTON', 400),
    ('2023-02-17 06:58:02', '30037-B', 'PUR-CT-100221-9', 'UNIT CARTON', 400),
    ('2023-02-17 06:58:52', '30037-B', 'PUR-CT-100221-9', 'UNIT CARTON', 400)
```

Puedes usar el suiguiente query *(incluso la suma quedaría en el mismo query)*:

```
SELECT OP, codigo, descripcion, SUM(a9) cantidad
FROM suaje
WHERE OP = '30037-C'
GROUP BY OP, codigo, descripcion;
```

Si quieres un solo registro con los datos coincidentes puedes usar la cláusula `GROUP BY`, pero debes excluir la columna fecha, ya que al ser diferente en cada registro te separaría los resultados.

El resultado sería algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto me funciono muy bien, lo unico que se me hizo raro es que el query de la consulta lo puse de manera lineal y no funciono, pero al colocarlo de manera en que lo muestras funciona, muchas gracias por la información.

Comment: Genial, me alegra que te haya servido!. Si gustas, dale al upvote para que futuros visitantes tengan una mejor referencia de la respuesta y para que sumemos reputación en la comunidad :)